# why I can't use the function adaptor compose2?

Tags: c++, stl, sgi

I use GCC 4.1.2 on linux, and the STL must be SGI STL.
After I wrote:

```
#include <functional>
 std::find_if(PirateFlush, PirateFlush + size,
                compose2(std::logical_and<bool>(), bind2nd(std::greater<UInt32>(), time),
                    bind2nd(std::less<UInt32>(), now)));
```

the compiler said:

error: ‘compose2’ was not declared in this scope

what's the matter?

Comment: +1 for `PirateFlush`. Flush those pirates, matey.

Comment: What makes you think it is the SGI STL? Did you install it yourself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`compose2` is not standard and is neither in the global nor `std` namespaces.

gcc ships some non-standard SGI extensions in the `__gnu_cxx` namespace.

Use `__gnu_cxx::compose2`, or boost has many of these predefined.

-nick